# Continuous function Limit Problem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Show that there exists only one continuous function $f(x)$ such that $y = f(x)$ satisfies the Kepler equation $y -\epsilon \sin y = x$ for $0 < \epsilon < 1$.

Comment: do your own homework

Comment: @user136266 : It is not considered the best practice to phrase posted questions in the style appropriate for assigning homework.

Comment: I dunno how to do thats why I am asking

Answer (score 2):

For a given $x$, there exists only 1 $y$ satisfying the equation (study the function $g(x) = x \rightarrow  x- \epsilon.\sin(x)$.
The inverse of a continuous bijective function is continuous

(a continuous bijective function is strictly monotonic (theorem of intermediate values), the inverse of a monotonic function is monotonic, and as it is bijective it will be continuous)

Comment: that's the thing that i dunno how to show

Comment: I edited the answer, ask here if you need more hints, but it should be enough